# SQL - one row to split into two columns snake

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table ( there can be up to 15 comment lines)

```
DeliveryNo|LineNo |CommentNo |CommentText
--------  |-------|----------|------------
2214518   |1      |1         |pre SS17 order                                              
2214518   |1      |2         |CHECK DELIVERY DATE
2214518   |1      |3         |02/11/2016
2214518   |1      |4         |For Attention
2214518   |1      |5         |Joe Soaps
```

Need the output to look like this

```
DeliveryNo| LineNo|Comment1           |Comment2
----------|-------|-------------------|------------
2214518   |1      |pre SS17 order     |CHECK DELIVERY DATE
2214518   |1      |02/11/2016         |For Attention
2214518   |1      |Joe Soaps          |
```

Comment: You have tagged mysql but your question infers you are using SQL Server 2012. Please correct your tags. That aside, look up a tutorial on "pivot".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation with `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
SELECT t.deliveryNo,
       t.lineNo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.CommentNo % 2 = 1 THEN t.commentText END) as comment1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t.CommentNo % 2 = 0 THEN t.commentText END) as comment2
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.deliveryNo,
         t.lineNo,
         CEIL(t.CommentNo / 2)
```

Comment: There should be only comment1 and comment2 in the output. Hence you may use `WHEN t.CommentNo % 2 = 1` for targeting comment1 and `WHEN t.CommentNo % 2 = 2` for targeting comment2.

Comment: Yea, didn't catch that. Fixed @FDavidov

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it ...

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Test') is not null drop table #Test

create table #Test (DeliveryNo bigint, Line int, CommentNo int, CommentText nvarchar(100))

insert into #Test(DeliveryNo, Line, CommentNo, CommentText)
values
(2214518   ,1      ,1         ,'pre SS17 order'),
(2214518   ,1      ,2         ,'CHECK DELIVERY DATE'),
(2214518   ,1      ,3         ,'02/11/2016'),
(2214518   ,1      ,4         ,'For Attention'),
(2214518   ,1      ,5         ,'Joe Soaps')

select t1.DeliveryNo, 
   t1.Line,
   t1.CommentText,
   t2.CommentText
from #Test t1
left join #Test t2 on t1.CommentNo = t2.CommentNo - 1
where t1.CommentNo % 2 = 1
```

Result is like you asked for

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    DeliveryNo,
    LineNo,
    A.CommentText as Comment1,
    B.CommentText as Comment2
    from table as A left join table as B
    on A.DeliveryNo=B.DeliveryNo and A.CommentNo=B.CommentNo-1
where (A.CommentNo mod 2) > 1
```